# How can I get to the northern-most part of Ortan Fields?

Tags: neptunia-rebirth-1

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to get to the area indicated with the white arrow. There's a ledge where the red line is that appears to be too high to jump up.

Is there a plan later that lets you jump higher? Am I missing something obvious regarding teleporters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plan that lets you jump higher. It is named Jumping Star and is acquired in chapter 5 via The Chirper (that is, those small conversations on the world map). To craft the plan requires 16 MB and an AG System.

To get the AG System you'll need to craft the Add Enemies plan for Mechtro Factory and defeat the Herobo. It's a robotic enemy you'll find to your right, not the Child Whales up ahead.

If you need to get a Random Encounters chip to craft the Add Enemies plan, you can get them from Dangerous Shampuru in Zeca Ruins No. 1. They're the dangerous monster that appear if you do not have Add Enemies for Zeca Ruins No. 1 activated. There's also one in a one-time treasure in Thelad Sanctuary.